# TRUE if some but not all elements are NA

Tags: r, if-statement

This cant be too hard, but I'm stuck.

```
x1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 2)
x2 <- c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 3)
x3 <- c(NA, NA, NA)
```

I have three possible vectors. They can either have no `NA`s (`x1`), some `NA`s (`x2`) or only `NA`s (`x3`). I want
an operation to be performed only when there are **some** `NA`s but not when there are only `NA`s.

How do I write the condition that returns `TRUE` only if some of the elements are `NA` (but `FALSE` when all or none of them are `NA`).

Desired output

- x1 FALSE
- x2 TRUE
- x3 FALSE

Comment: `?anyNA` perhaps?

Comment: `sum(is.na(x)) < length(x)`

Comment: but anyNA is true of x3 as well

Comment: @ManuelR yes, I corrected the comment.

Comment: ok so `any(is.na(x1)) & sum(is.na(x) < length(x1))

Comment: `!all(is.na(x)) & anyNA(x)` would work?

Comment: @DavidArenburg this should be the answer!

Comment: @DavidArenburg yes that does the trick. Will you post the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `all` and `is.na`

```
all_NA <- function(x) ! (all(is.na(x)) | all(!is.na(x)))

all_NA(x3)
#[1] FALSE
all_NA(x2)
#[1] TRUE
all_NA(x1)
#[1] FALSE
```

Or a bit simpler version (which looks similar to @David's solution in the comments)

```
all_NA <- function(x) any(is.na(x)) & !all(is.na(x))
```

Comment: or: `any(is.na(x)) & ! all(is.na(x))`